# angular http TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

**EditComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemIndex = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.editModu = this.itemIndex != null == true;
    // subscription for dropdown images
    this.apiPokemons.getPokedexs().subscribe(data => {
      
      this.pokedex = data
    });

    if(this.editModu){
      this.apiPokemons.getPokemon(this.itemIndex).subscribe((response: Pokemon) => {
        // console.log(response)
        
        this.pokemonAddForm = new FormGroup({
          'username': new FormControl(response.pokemon,Validators.required),
          gender: new FormControl(response.gender,Validators.required),
          region: new FormControl(response.trainer_region,Validators.required),
          birthDay: new FormControl(response.birth_year,Validators.required),
          pokedexName: new FormControl(response.pokedexData,Validators.required)  
      })
      }); 
    }else{
        this.pokemonAddForm = new FormGroup({
          'username': new FormControl("", [Validators.required,/*this.isValidUsername.bind(this)*/]), //not called it like required() we just passing the reference and angular will execute
          'region': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
          'gender': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
          'birthDay': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
          'pokedexName': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        })
      
      }
    
    
    
    //initiliazing the form
    
  }


  onSubmit() {
    // let pokedexId = this.pokedex.findIndex(this.pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').value)
    console.log(this.pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').value)
    // console.log("pokedexID:"+pokedexId)
    this.user = {
      pokemon: this.pokemonAddForm.controls['username'].value,
      gender: this.pokemonAddForm.get('gender').value,
      trainer_region: this.pokemonAddForm.get('region').value,
      birth_year: this.pokemonAddForm.get('birthDay').value,
      pokedexData:this.pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').value
      // this.pokedex[this.pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').value]
      // console.log(this.pokedexData)
    
    }
    console.log("the user")
    console.log(this.user)

    //update the user
    if (this.editModu) {
      this.apiPokemons.upDatePokemon(this.itemIndex, this.pokemonAddForm.value)
      this.toast.open('successfully updated Pokemon')
      
    }

    //add the userdata to service
    else {
      console.log('adding the data')
      this.apiPokemons.addPokemon(this.user);
      this.toast.open('successfully added new Pokemon')
      
    }
    // reset form
    this.pokemonAddForm.reset()

    // redirect to home
    this.router.navigate(['/pokemons'])
  }
```

**ApiService.ts**

```
upDatePokemon(id:number, updatePokemon:Pokemon){
        // updatePokemon.id = id;
        const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            .append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
            console.log(`${this.pokemonsPath}${id}/`)
        return this.http.patch(`${this.pokemonsPath}${id}/`, updatePokemon, {headers:headers}).subscribe((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYvej.png)

**before the data retrieve this is running and giving error**

```
 <span *ngIf="!pokemonAddForm.get('username').valid && pokemonAddForm.controls['username'].touched && isLoading">
                        <span *ngIf="pokemonAddForm.get('username').errors['anAllowdUserName']">Already Exists userName!</span>
                        <span *ngIf="pokemonAddForm.get('username').errors['required']">Please Enter valid Name!</span></span>
```

**form.html**

```
<form  [formGroup]="pokemonAddForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
                <div id="user-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Pokeman Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control"   name="name"
                            formControlName='username'>
                        <span *ngIf="!pokemonAddForm.get('username').valid && pokemonAddForm.controls['username'].touched && isLoading">
                        <span *ngIf="pokemonAddForm.get('username').errors['anAllowdUserName']">Already Exists userName!</span>
                        <span *ngIf="pokemonAddForm.get('username').errors['required']">Please Enter valid Name!</span></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text">Trainer Region</label>
                        <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control" ngDefaultControl formControlName='region' name="country">
                        <span *ngIf="!pokemonAddForm.get('region').valid && pokemonAddForm.get('region').touched">
                            Please Enter your Region!
                        </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <select id="gender" class="form-control"  formControlName='gender' name="option">
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="date">Birth Date</label>
                    <input type="date" id="text" class="form-control"  formControlName='birthDay' name="date">
                    <span *ngIf="!pokemonAddForm.get('birthDay').valid && pokemonAddForm.get('birthDay').touched ">
                        enter Your BirthDay please
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- file input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-label>Choose your Favourite pokedex</mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName='pokedexName'>
                            <mat-option>Choose your Favourite pokedex</mat-option>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let pk of pokedex" [value]="pk.id"  >
                                <img [src]='pk.imagePath' width="100px" height="80px"> {{pk.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <span *ngIf="!pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').valid && pokemonAddForm.get('pokedexName').touched">
                        Please Select your Favourite Pokedex
                    </span>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary form-control " type="submit" [disabled]='!pokemonAddForm.valid'>Add Pokemon</button>
            </form>
```

before data retrieve from the API the form is rendering, I cannot get the data that I made changes in the form just returning the old one and sending the service.
how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're building the form too late. either add null checks in your template like:

```
*ngIf="!pokemonAddForm?.get('username').valid
```

everywhere you're accessing the form in template.. or wrap everything in a big ngIf...

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pokemonAddForm">
  <!-- all other content -->
</ng-container>
```

or build the form much earlier (in the constructor) and populate it later with the response...

```
  constructor(/* injections */) {
    this.pokemonAddForm = new FormGroup({
      'username': new FormControl("", [Validators.required,/*this.isValidUsername.bind(this)*/]), //not called it like required() we just passing the reference and angular will execute
      'region': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      'gender': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      'birthDay': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      'pokedexName': new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.itemIndex = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.editModu = this.itemIndex != null == true;
    // subscription for dropdown images
    this.apiPokemons.getPokedexs().subscribe(data => {
  
      this.pokedex = data
    });

    if(this.editModu){
      this.apiPokemons.getPokemon(this.itemIndex).subscribe((response: Pokemon) => {
        // console.log(response)
        
        this.pokemonAddForm.reset({
          'username': response.pokemon,
          gender: response.gender,
          region: esponse.trainer_region,
          birthDay: response.birth_year,
          pokedexName: response.pokedexData,
        })
      }); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: building the form earlier is worked but still am trying to figure out the idea behind this, is this means before retrieving any data it has to run first the html?

Comment: You’re calling get on your form in template before it’s initialized Because retrieving the data is taking too long. You need to initialize the form before the view starts evaluating expressions, so you build the form first then populate it later once you have the data